# Lack of convergence in metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis

For metric spaces (M,d) and (N,p), with a function that goes from M to N is continuous on M, can we say that if a sequence does not converge in (M,d) it also does not converge in (N,p)? I'm familiar with the idea that if this sequence does converge in (M,d), it will also converge in (N,p), but I'm not sure if the opposite is true, or how I could go about proving such a thing. Sorry for the poor formatting, I'm on my very persnickety phone, and I thought of this while in bed inthe middle of the night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opposite is false. Take, for example, $M$ to be the interval $[0,2\pi)$ and $N$ to be the unit circle, with the mapping $f:M\to N$ given by $t\to (\cos t,\sin t)$. This mapping is continuous, the sequence $1/2,2\pi-1/2, 1/3,2\pi-1/3,1/4,2\pi-1/4,\dots$ does not converge in $M$ but the sequence of images converges to the point with coordinates $(1,0)$ in $N$.

Answer (score 1):

That opposite claim is false. Here's a simple example. Let $M=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric and $N=\{0\}$ (with the only possible metric on it: $p(0,0)=0$). The function $f:M\to N$ defined as $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in M=\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. The sequence $a_k=k$ for $k=1,2,3\ldots$ diverges in $M$, but the sequence $f(a_k)=f(k)=0$ converges in $N$.